# How to convert a local text file to an array and display its elements using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

abc.txt

John
22-08-1998
Bangalore
1111111111

```html
const k;
this.k = sessionStorage.getItem('loggedUser');
if (k.UpperCase() === 'MEGHANA') {
  const fs = require('fs')
  const text = fs.readFileSync('./MEGHANA.txt').toString('utf-8')
  const textByLine = text.split('\n')
  document.write(textByLine[0])
}
```

Comment: `const textByLine = text.split('\n')` gives you the whole line which you'd like to parse in to an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this code is what you mean!

```
const k;
this.k = sessionStorage.getItem('loggedUser');
if (k.UpperCase() === 'MEGHANA') {
  const fs = require('fs');
  const text = fs.readFileSync('./MEGHANA.txt').toString('utf-8');
  const textByLine = text.split('\n');
  const textArray = textByLine[0].split(' ');
  textArray.forEach(t => document.write(t));
}
```